# Joomla Limit Custom Pagination

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, paging

In Joomla 2.5 for paging we have getPagesLinks() function.

If i have more than 100 records then it gives Start Prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Next End.

I want like Start Prev 1 2 Next End.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the output in the template: http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Pagination_Links_Overrides

The pagination object also has some properties which are of interest:

- pagesCurrent
- pagesStart
- pagesStop
- pagesTotal

That should allow you to create what you want. By setting Start and Stop depending on Current and Total.